# Putting space between every two bars in seaborn's factorplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, figure

I have a drawn a plot using seaborn and the following command:

```
ax = sns.factorplot(x="feat", y="acc", col="roi", hue="alpha", data=df_d_pt, kind="bar", dodge=True)
```

Results look like this:

[image]

But I want to put space between every two bars, that is bars with dark blue and light blue would be very close to each other but some space between the dard blue bar and the light green one (and so on...)

How can I do that?

Update, data looks like this:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: There doesn't seem to exist an easy way to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] of the data?

Comment: Thank you for updating but an image is **not** reproducible. Please read [how to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464) make sure to craft the example to reproducibility show the desired bars, not just the first and last one.